# Mixed Integer Linear Programming: Construction Rods

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, applications, integer-programming

I have an interesting problem involving linear programming. The problem is the following, I have 4 different kinds of rods (rod sized found in the local market):

- 9m rod
- 11m rod
- 12m rod
- 15m rod

Slabs on construction have steel rods and I want to minimize the quantity of rods used horizontally and vertically. I have a total length (Ltotal) and I want to know what is the **minimum amount of rods** I need to use for a slab,that still fits at least inside it or possibly longer. The remaining rod length that exceeds the slab is going to be cut. So I suppose the **objective function** will be:

$$
\min  x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}
$$

$$s.t. \  9x_{1} + 11x_{2} + 12x_{3} + 15x_{4}\  \ (\lt,\le or =)? \ \ \ L_{total}$$
$$ x_{1} \ge 0$$
$$ x_{2} \ge 0$$
$$ x_{3} \ge 0$$
$$ x_{4} \ge 0$$
where

$x_{1}$: total amount of 9m rods used 
$x_{2}$: total amount of 11m rods used 
$x_{3}$: total amount of 12m rods used 
$x_{4}$: total amount of 15m rods used

I assume all this 4 variables should be integers(MILP)

The constraint expresses the amount of rods multiplied by its length should be less than or equal to the total length. I want some advice as I am not very familiar to optimization methods. I put this same example in PuLP but it throwed 0 for all values.

I need help to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You swapped an inequality. If the total length should be *less* than some specified total length, the trivial solution is to set all lengths equal to zero, as you have obtained numerically.

Comment: Hi @JohanLöfberg , should I set it as an equality instead? How would you set it?

Comment: Does it make sense to you to specify that the length of the rod should be *less* than some value? Just think in terms of common sense. If you tell your welder to build the cheapest possible rod, and it has to be *at most* 10 meters, any smart welder would give you a rod of length 0 and happily take your money. Hence you should specify that the rod should be...

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, oh I see but the total length is not the length of the rod but the length of the entire slab(Ltotal). I have to find a configuration of the given rods(rods in the market) that fit in the slab.

Comment: Then you are obviously missing some constraint, as the trivially optimal solution is $x=0$ (or actually $x = -\infty$ as you do not have any non-negativity constraint on $x$). A rod of length 0 clearly fits in your slab.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I added the constraints now, I modified my post. Should the constraints be $\ge$ or $\gt$. Is the constraint stated correctly? I don't have any background on optimization whatsoever, I started reading about this yesterday and there many things I don't know about LP.

Comment: There must still be something missing. You say that something you design should fit inside something given and I interpret that as the constraint $ 9x_1+11x_2+12x_3+15x_4 \leq L_{total}$ (something should have a total length less than something, otherwise it is too big). Don't you agree with me that the trivial solution $x=0$ is the best possible? What, in practical terms, tells you that you do not want that solution. Nothing in your verbal description or mathematical description says it is a bad choice.

Comment: I agree it to be the best possible solution. Practically, I need it to be nontrivial obviously. 1) How would I state my problem to obtain a solution other than the trivial? I want the number of rods needed to make the slab, I want it to be using the smallest amount of rods that fit on it. 2)I obtained a solution yesterday if make the constraint an equality(Why?).

Comment: So if you need a non-trivial solution (i.e. not $0$) then the optimal solution would be to pick the cheapest $x_i$ to be $1$ and the rest zero. In your case, all cost the same, so we just pick $x_1=1$ and the rest $0$. That is the optimal non-zero solution. The model is still weird. Should the rod be longer than the slab? You say it should fit *in* (as inside, being smaller) the slab, but perhaps you mean it should cover the slab.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean it should be as long as possible, while still fitting inside, and when as long as possible, use as few parts as possible?

Comment: Your last comment nails it, should be the way I should have stated the constraint. I suppose that a smaller rod is cheaper than a bigger rod. Is it a little bit clearer now? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Now you updated the question in a way that is inconsistent with what you just said. Now you say "I need to use for a slab,that still fits inside it(it could be longer)." Still fits inside but could be longer? That statement says absolutely nothing. Does it have to fit inside the slab of length $L_{total}$, or does it have to be at least as long as the slab, possibly even being longer?

Comment: When I say It could be longer, I meant the following, suppose I have a 51.6 meter long slab, a possible solution could be three 15m rod and 9m rod or the variable is not limited to integers it'll be 3.44 15m rods. So it will be it has to be at "least as long as the slab, possibly even longer".

Comment: Then your problem is something completely different from wehat you have been saying recently. You are now saying that the design has to be at least $L_{total}$ long, and now you don't even have an integer problem as you accept non-integer length on rods? If so, you should simply use $\geq$, as you want it to be as long or longer than $L_{total}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited as the problem definition keeps changing. With the current desrciption in the comments, you have simply used the wrong inequality.

$$
\min x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}
$$

$$s.t. \  9x_{1} + 11x_{2} + 12x_{3} + 15x_{4}\ \geq L_{total}$$
$$ x_{1} \ge 0$$
$$ x_{2} \ge 0$$
$$ x_{3} \ge 0$$
$$ x_{4} \ge 0$$